# GMP handle overflow

Tags: php, gmp

I have following PHP script which I call via CLI:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$max_stellen = 10;

for ($base=2; $base<=62; $base++) {
        for ($power=2; $power<=10; $power++) {
                $result = array();

                $max_base = gmp_pow($base, $max_stellen);
                $x = gmp_init(0);

                while ((gmp_cmp($x, $max_base) == -1)) {
                        $val = gmp_strval($x, $base);
                        $i = strlen($val);

                        $left  = gmp_pow($x, $power);
                        $right = gmp_pow($base, $i);
                        $mod   = gmp_mod($left, $right);
                        if (gmp_cmp($mod, $x) == 0) {
                                $result[] = $val;
                        }
                        unset($left);
                        unset($right);
                        unset($mod);

                        $x = gmp_add($x, 1); // !!! line 30
                }

                unset($x);
                unset($max_base);

                $res2 = array();
                foreach ($result as &$r) {
                        $root = substr($r, -1);
                        $res2[$root][] = $r;
                }
                unset($result);

                foreach ($res2 as $root => &$r) {
                        echo "X^${power}_${base}($root) = {".implode(', ', $r)."}\n";
                }
                unset($res2);

                echo "\n";
        }
}
```

After a short time (values `base=6, power=9`), I get following error message:

**PHP Warning:  gmp_add(): -2147483648 is not a valid GMP integer resource in ... on line 30**

If I manually run the code with `base=6, power=9`, it works, so the error only happens when the loop is running multiple times.

The error message sounds like there are GMP handles allocated which are not freed when they are not used anymore. So after a short time, the handle is out of integer range. But how do I free GMP handles? I already tried to use `unset()` everywhere, and functions like `gmp_free()` or `gmp_destroy()` do not exist.

**Update**

Reported issue to PHP, since I believe that it is not an expected behavior: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69702

Comment: 1. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with this code? 2. How many times do you expect that while loop to run during a single iteration of the inner for loop that you actually have to use a GMP integer to count the number of iterations done by it? I'd be surprised to hear that you can't fit them in a regular integer (I'm referring to the $x variable here)

Comment: The purpose of this piece of code is a test against immortal numbers in different bases.
As you can see in the code, `$x` will be counted up to `$max_base` , which can reach max. `62^10` . That is way over the limit of integers which is `2^32` .
What I want to do in line 30 is to increase `$x` by 1. Alas, this doesn't seem to be possible in PHP without always creating a new object using `gmp_add()`. And it is probably a bug in PHP that object reference IDs don't get resetted when the object is freed. So, the object reference ID reaches its integer limit.

Comment: In C++ (using the `mpz_` functions) it works, because there the `mpz_add_ui()` function can increase a BigInteger without re-creating the object.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I hope you have a really good reason to implement this in PHP, because I expect it to be slow compared to, say, C++.

Comment: Also, couldn't you use a 64 bit version of PHP? On such a platform, you can easily fit your counter into a regular integer: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c67765a5142452f0fc9b4476f3a3aad3bc0014ef

Comment: This PHP is running on a 64 bit Debian. Weird that it isn't 64 Bit. I implemented it in PHP because it is my favorite language, and this calculation was supposed to only run once. Now I implemented it in C, and it works. However, I still want to know why the GMP implemention of PHP has such a flaw, and if there is a workaround I have overseen. Something like a "big integer for-loop" shouldn't be impossible

Comment: I think it might be caused by the way in which the PHP GC works. You're initializing all those variables ($val, $i, $left, $right, $mod) inside the while loop. If the optimizer is not smart enough, it might just be the case that during each iteration, a new set of variables is created and perhaps the GC doesn't have a chance to kick in before the handle pool is exhausted. Out of curiosity, I would try to initialize all these variables outside the loop, and then simply reset them during each iteration. Otherwise, you'd probably have to read the PHP source code to understand the problem...